# Uploading the s3 error The XML you provided was not well-formed

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, multer

This is the output I'm seeing in the terminal.

```
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '161.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: '../uploads/',
  filename: '9152edf1ad886a4241d89374c5edaa8f',
  path: '..\\uploads\\9152edf1ad886a4241d89374c5edaa8f',
  size: 163804 }

Unhandled rejection MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or di
d not validate against our published schema
```

And my code as below

```
router.post('/image', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  var file = req.file;
  console.log(file)
   var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path); 

   return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.originalFilename, stream).then(function () { 
        fs.unlink(file.path, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });
        res.status(200).end();
    });
});
```

Not sure what's wrong, everything seems make sense to me. The only thing that seem strange to me is the path's value, why it has double `\\`

Comment: Where is the error coming from? The `unlink` method?

Comment: @Houseman I think it's the writeFile method, my file didn't go to S3

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler did you fix this in the end?